# What happened to my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Something weird/terrible just happened to my account and my sister's account. Somehow they got mixed up. We were using the same computer. We are panicking!! My sister seems to have my account points and my picture. This is horrible and we don't know what to do. My account is necronet. At this point we do not want to continue trying to fix it. We need some advice.

Comment: From the sounds of it, they probably got merged..

Comment: What can i do in that case?

Answer (score 13):

This is my fault - you both logged in using the same email (on different sites), so the system flagged it as likely someone trying to get into their account. I saw you'd both logged in from the same IP and assumed this was the case and merged.

I'll see what I can do to sort this out; no promises though.

Comment: awesome...we were panicking and crying over here...;( Thank you.

Comment: Don't stop panicking just yet; there is an "undo", but in my hands it breaks things as often as it fixes them - try not to log in or anything for the next, say, 30 minutes.

Comment: OK we will be holding our breaths...;(

Comment: Ok; this is probably as good as it's going to get... If you find posts attached to the wrong account somewhere, email me & I'll get it sorted out. And please, be *very* careful when sharing a machine to always use separate browsers and/or log out of *everything* when you're done - not just Stack Exchange, but Google, Facebook, etc.

Comment: cayerdis say: seems like my brother account is better . But when I login to my drupal account exchange instead of see my proile I see my brothers http://stackoverflow.com/users/3128399/cayerdis ;(

Comment: Shucks... I'll have to get this sorted out tomorrow then, I'm afraid.

Comment: It just goes to show; no good deed goes unpunished! :-P